# Do custom parameters in Google Adwords include the curly braces?

Tags: google-ads

I'm setting up an ad using a Custom parameter in Google Adwords.  I've configured the Ad URL Options section as follows:

[image]

Which of the following URLs will this configuration link to?

- `http://example.com/?_ad=101`
- `http://example.com/?{_ad}=101`

(In other words, the curly braces are confusing to me - are they included in the final URL?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  I needed the following configuration:

[image]

... which leads to the following URL (no curly braces):

`http://example.com/?ad=101`